# calling R (2.15.3) from within R (3.0.2)

Tags: r

I would like to be able to call R (2.15.3) from within R (3.0.2). In order to use a package (windows binary, not on cran) that is available in only the older version of R. Is this possible?

Comment: which package is that?

Comment: Why not build from the package source into 3.0.2?

Comment: you could make a `system()` or `shell()` call to run an R batch file (e.g. `system("/path/to/old/R CMD BATCH mybatchfile.R")`, but a little bit more context about what you're trying to do would probably be helpful ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This is R. There is no if, only how

said Simon Blomberg.

You could call an older version of R using `system()` and the appropriate hacks in your OS. Which is something odd to do, and opens tons of possibilities for serious damage to your computer when you hit it in frustration.

Or you could download the source of the package and rebuild it in R 3.0. There's been some rather drastic internal changes in the way packages are built and used in R (the most obvious being the removal of support for packages without a namespace).

Hence :

- if the package does not have a namespace: download the source (.tar.gz), read the manual "[Writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)" if you didn't before, and add a namespace file with the usual exports. As explained in Writing R extensions, this can be as simple as adding a single line

  ```
  exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
  ```
- if the package has a namespace, build from source on your machine and you should be good to go. This is simply done by using:

  ```
  install.packages("path/to/package.tar.gz",type="source")
  ```

Note that if you want to install from source on a Windows machine, you'll need a compatible version of Rtools : http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

If you don't want to be bothered with it, mail the author/maintainer of the package and kindly ask if they'd like to rebuild it for you.

Comment: It's not clear from the context we have so far whether this package is unavailable for 3.0.2 because it (1) just hasn't been built for 3.0.2 (and may or may not have any compiled components that require `Rtools`); (2) has minor adjustments (e.g. `NAMESPACE`/`DESCRIPTION` tweaks) required for compatibility; (3) has non-trivial compatibility problems.

Comment: I know. Hence the different options. I doubt there are non-trivial compatibility problems when moving from R 2.15 to R 3.0. At least, I haven't found a package where any compatibility problem isn't solved by simply rebuilding (and adding a namespace file).